# Java doFilter() throws NPE as part of a superclass

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Okay - I've been doing some work with Java filters at work lately, and we often have to recycle code when moving between web apps; we can make the filters look at a relative location so that they can be used across multiple contexts, but we still go through a lot of them. So, I've created a superclass to aid in code production; I also added the runFilter method as an abstract method in the superclass, just to keep it separate from the standard doFilter. The superclass code looks like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        runFilter(req,resp,chain);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().error("Error! Exception:",e);
    }
}
```

Now, here's the problem: whenever a filter extending the above code triggers, I get errors like I set up in the logger above, but I also get the logger messages from inside the child class's runFilter indicating that it's doing its job - the forwarding even works as it ought. I look at my console, and it's showing errors occurring on the lines where the child class is accessing the filter chain.

```
if (isExcluded(debugURI)) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    } else if (request.getSession().getAttribute("USER") == null) {
        getLogger().info("Session with ID " + serialVersionUID + " has timed out. Redirecting to " + getRedirectTarget() + ".");
        response.sendRedirect(getRedirectTarget()); 
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

Does the FilterChain need to be updated (or extended) in order to receive a call for runFilter, as well? Any help would be very useful.

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the concrete question/problem. Please clarify. The only thing which isn't right in the code is the `doFilter()` call after the `sendRedirect()`. This is just not right. Get rid of that line. But this does not seem to match the vague description of the NPE-related problem. Again, please clarify.

Comment: and on top of what BalusC said above, posting the actual NPE trace would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across this error very early in my work with servlets; the problem is quite simple, actually. I had errors being generated from within the superclass because each filter instantiation failed at a fundamental level; however, the real blunder was my attempt to call the doFilter method after a sendRedirect - since the sendRedirect method terminates the chain, I was attempting to access a stub. Any redirection needs to be handled within the filter chain, because a sendRedirect terminates it.